# Cannot add a Fragment to an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

Adding a fragment to an activity.

My Activity that extends BaseActivity:

```
 @Bind(R.id.layout_frame_container) protected FrameLayout mFrameContainer;

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_saved_searches_container);

        if(null == savedInstanceState){
            String screenTitle = getIntent().getExtras().getString(AppConstants.KEY_SCREEN_TITLE);
            FCoreFragment savedSearchFragment = FSavedSearchesList.instance(screenTitle);
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(mFrameContainer, savedSearchFragment).commit(); //I GET AN ERROR HERE CANT RESOLVE METHOD
        }
    }
```

FSavedSearchesList extends FCoreFragment which extends Fragment(`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`)

`mFrameContainer` is the FrameLayout id.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout_frame_container">

</FrameLayout>
```

So `savedSearchFragment` should be of type Fragment.

Could you let me know how I can fix this?

here is the error:

```
C:\Development\Android\TrendsFragment.java
Warning:(628, 36) non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
cast to Object for a varargs call
cast to Object[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning
C:\Development\Android\salesiMobile\src\main\java\com\salesi\mobile\module\accounts\ui\container\SavedSearchesContainer.java
Error:(39, 32) error: no suitable method found for add(FrameLayout,FCoreFragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; FrameLayout cannot be converted to Fragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; FrameLayout cannot be converted to int)
Error:Execution failed for task ':salesiMobile:compileRefactorDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 18.121 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:1 warning
Information:See complete output in console
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the fields in below code to call any fragment.If u want to call your fragment via Instance method then you can change it while creating Fragment Object below.

```
    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
    if (arguments != null) {
      fragment.setArguments(arguments);
      arguments = null;
    }
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
        android.R.anim.fade_out);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, arguments);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` for support Fragment because you use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and use the id of FrameLayout which is `R.id.layout_frame_container`:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

...

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.layout_frame_container, savedSearchFragment)
                   .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

While adding fragments    `fragmentTransaction.add(mFrameContainer, savedSearchFragment).commit();`
 usually expects container id instead of reference.
Change `mFrameContainer` to `R.id.layout_frame_container` and it should work.

Also since you are using android.support.v4.app.Fragment change the manager from `getFragmentManager()` to `getSupportFragmentManager().`

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Comment: That did not fix it

Answer (score 0):

Create container

```
       <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Use this MainActivity.java class define fragment manager and transection globel

```
        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.container, new Home_Fragment(), 
       "Home_Fragment").commit();
```

Answer (score -1):

Create FrameLayout container in your xml file.

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Open your java class and Define fragment manager with transaction.

```
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Your_Fragment your_Fragment=new Your_Fragment();
            replaceFragment(your_Fragment);
    }

    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
```